# How to set app start screen background color in WinRT

Tags: windows-runtime

How do you set the background color of the start screen (AKA Splash Screen) in a WinRT app? The default is dark gray which is quite not friendly to the eye.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In app manifest, there is "Application UI" tab, Set the "Background color" entry to the desired color.

This has now moved to the "Visual Assets" tab, and you then need to select "Splash Screen" before setting the "Background color".

Comment: @JoshGreifer, I think winrt documentation is still lacking, so anything that is about it is helpful. As for this issue, I googled quite a bit and found nothing related, then I played around a bit and found the answer, felt that maybe my finding could help someone else, hence the question.